# What is the state of Open Source Java?

Tags: open-source, jvm, java

**What is the current state of Java's transition to an open source license** (which [Wikipedia lists as the GNU General Public License / Java Community Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29))?

Java being inclusive of many things, including:

- The JVM
- The JRE
- The JDK
- The Core Java Libraries
- JavaME
- JavaEE

I've heard/read various things, but never seen it laid out in a straight, definitive, manner. However if you know about only a subsection of Java, don't hesitate to add an answer.

Just to clarify, this question is about the **current** state of the process, not what Sun may or may not do in the future.

Comment: Jou've forgotten to list JavaFX, which is indeed significant, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've quite rightly pointed out, Java encompasses a large number of components; I'm not sure that you'll be able to get a definitive answer that clarifies all the intricacies here.

However, based on various licensing that I've read so far, Java is (supposed to be) fully GPL'd now with the exception of the SNMP implementation which is still encumbered. This includes all of items you've stated, with the possible exception of Java EE. (I don't know much about that)

With regards to the state of the process; there doesn't appear to be much progress on replacing the SNMP implementation. I would therefore take the view that Java 6 will not be fully GPL compliant.

Java 7 looks like it will be fully GPL compliant from the info that Sun have been giving out. But that's not due for release until 2010 - and that's a tentative timescale.

Comment: OpenJDK 6 is a backport of OpenJDK 7. So why wouldn't that be fully GPL?

Comment: That may be the case entirely; you obviously know more about that than myself. I was referring to the Sun JDK.

Answer (score 5):

I can't say that I know all that much about the current transition/process, but I can tell you that the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) (see also [OpenJDK on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)), specifically OpenJDK 6 is good enough to be used in place of the Sun Java JDK 6 release, and it has now been [certified by Canonical for use in Ubuntu Jaunty](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Ubuntu-9-04-Receives-OpenJDK-6-Certification-116630.shtml).

Comment: I tried it. It works, but MetalThemUI is ... off somehow. Stuff is not in the right place and it looks BAD.

Answer (score 5):

Even though OpenJDK makes Java's implementation open, there have been still [some concerns](http://blog.joda.org/2009/03/no-more-java-7_2394.html) because Java's specification is not open.

Comment: I wonder if he'll comment on this? According to his profile (http://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), he hasn't visited for several days.

Answer (score 4):

You won't get a definitive answer here on SO.  Or on Wikipedia.  Or on gnu.org.

If there is any such thing as a *definitive answer*, it is what Sun says on the [Free and Open Source Java](http://www.sun.com/software/opensource/java/) page.

Any summary I make will be non-definitive, so I won't.

Comment: @Tshepang - the page no longer exists on the Oracle website.  You can see what it used to look like using the Wayback Machine: http://www.archive.org/web/web.php.  I'm not going to search the Oracle site for Oracle's latest pronouncements.  But if you do, and if you find something significant, feel free to update my answer to this question, or create one of your own.

Comment: I can't find it using Google. Use this link instead http://web.archive.org/web/20080822032650/www.sun.com/software/opensource/java/index.jsp.

Comment: I'm not sure that the old version is relevant anymore.  Ir certainly not relevant for finding out the **current** Oracle position.